# How to send a message through socket fron DLL on application closing?

Tags: c++, delphi, sockets, dll

I have a DLL written in C++ to be consumed by our clients - third party developers in their applications. The DLL has some facilities in to connect to our company's servers through winsock and communicate with the servers on a specific protocol.

The outstanding task is to send a kind of farewell message to the active server on application closing. But the only way of getting known about the event (application closing) I am aware about is DllMain/DLL_PROCESS_DETACH case. I know that it is not recommended, I read [Raymond Chen's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/05/10253268.aspx) about this and MSDN documentation, but instead of cautions I need a solution.

Of course I did a try to send the message from DllMain, but it seemed that at that moment winsock library had been already detached, as what I received was WSANOTINITIALISED (10093) error.

Also I tried to create a static finalizer like the following:

```
struct Finalization
{
    ~Finalization() {
        // sending the message
    }
};

static Finalization f;
```

without success either.

I feel that what I need is somewhat like a trigger point to know, when the process is going to terminate. The case of simultaneous using the library can be ignored, as its specific leaves absolutely no sense in that.

What I am thinking about is that the library is bundled with an interface header, that is going to be included in the customer's application. I could use the fact to place something in the file, a mutex or something like that.

Maybe it's worth mentioning that the previous version of the library was written in Delphi, and the parting message was sending from one of finalization sections, and it worked perfectly, perhaps just by chance.

Thank you in advance for your ideas.

Comment: Couldn't you export a function like `sendFarewell()` or similar from the dll and call this function from you application when it's about to close?

Comment: @Krister Andersson. Yes, such function does exist. And it's clearly stated in the documentation to call it before exit. And the server finalizes the session correctly on disconnection (but with timeout). But it's the requirement to send that message on exit, at least because the old dll did that, and the new one is going to bear the same logic.

Comment: Let me be more clear. If you're able to call WSAGetLastError, then winsock is not detached.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz. The task is not to avoid the error, but send the message.

Comment: @Silver - I don't know how can I be more clear. Winsock is not detached/unloaded or anything since you're calling WSAGetLastError with success. You may have an error unrelated with the process detaching from the dll. Why is winsock not initated? Does WSAStartup fail when you call it while the process is detaching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your DLL functions that initialise and finalise the DLL. Make it so that all consumers of the DLL call these functions. In the finalise function you can do whatever it is that you wish to do.

As you have discovered, leaving it to DllMain is no good. There's no way for you to escape that. DllMain is simply the wrong place to attempt socket comma.

Comment: Such functions exist, but since the client applications are out of our control, the requireement is to force the DLL sending that message. Another reason for doing that is to exactly reproduce the deprecated version's interface and behaviour.

Comment: Well, it's either this way, or `DllMain`.

Comment: Another option might be to increment a counter each time a  `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` notification is received, then decrement the counter each time a `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` notification is received. When the counter falls to 0 on the last `DLL_THREAD_DETACH`, do whatever cleanup you need.  The DLL will not have been detached from the process yet.